# Durandal - how to route parametrized module at levels with a different no. of parameters?

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

While the direct mapping of route parameters to activate() parameters is convenient, it poses a problem for me for the reuse of parametrized modules.

Take a route like e.g.

```
{ route: '/user/:id/request(/:requestId)', moduleId: 'requestDetail', title: 'Request Details' }
```

The viewmodel will be called with

```
activate(id,requestId)
```

Now, the requestDetail module could be reused at different positions and levels in navigation, like so

**parent router**

```
{ route: '/company/:companyId*users', moduleId: 'someModule', title: 'Request Details' }
```

**child router**

```
{ route: '/user/:id/request(/:requestId)', moduleId: 'requestDetail', title: 'Request Details' }
```

which has the effect of the requestDetail vm being called with

```
activate(companyId,id,requestId)
```

which obviously is a problem.
Is there any way to restrict the passed parameters to those coming from the child router (which would solve the problem)?